# ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::TooManyRecords error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, nested-attributes

In my app, when user register they can upload some files. I need to limit the upload to maximum 5 files. So I have two model with following code

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :fileuploads, :dependent => :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :fileuploads, limit: 5, :allow_destroy => true

  validate do |user|
    if user.fileuploads && user.fileuploads.count > 5
      errors[:base] << "You can add maximum 5 files."
    end
  end  
end
```

and

```
class Fileupload < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and in my create and update action I added

```
respond_to do |format|
  begin
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: I18n.t('views.flash_messages.user_was_successfully_created') }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::TooManyRecords
    flash[:error] = 'You can add maximum 5 files. '
  end
end
```

As you can see from the code above that, I am using `limit: 5` and also the `validate` callback. But both works perfect when I update the user. But when user is created, this error message is not rescued at all. I get this error,

```
ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::TooManyRecords in UsersController#create
Maximum 5 records are allowed. Got 7 records instead.
```

So why the limit and validate works during user update but not during user creation? And how to make it work for create action as well?

Comment: Did you check your html codes with navigator console if there are 7 records in form in your views ?

Comment: yes! also if i select 5 files then it save the user but if I select more than 5 then I get error. But instead of error I want to rescue the error  which is not working for user create but works for user update.

Comment: inside begin & rescue block you perform @user.save where you add the params to user line User.new(params[:user])?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what is working for me now. Better solutions are welcome.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :fileuploads, :dependent => :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :fileuploads, limit: 5, :allow_destroy => true

after_create :count_files

def count_files
    if self.fileuploads && self.fileuploads.count > 5
      errors[:base] << "You can add maximum 5 files."
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
end
```